# How can I get the mobile dropdown menu from Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

If you go to bootstrap's main website on your phone, you'll notice a slide down menu on the top right.

This is part of the nav bar.

Where can I find this dropdown menu plugin? It's not on the main site.

Comment: Where is it on the main site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the Responsive Navbar - the variation that shows on mobiles. To find it and see its usage, read Carlo's comment or go here:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Answer (score 1):

See this example:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Remember to add:

```
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

And the css:

```
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is code sample:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
              Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
            </p>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a result of the responsive css `bootstrap-responsive.css`

It shows different on the mobile due to the device width detection.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to download specifically the responsive navbar component , you can do so by goin on to the [**Customize BootStrap**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html)  and then select the navbar,navs,tabs and pills and then in responsive section You can select the responsive navbar option and other media components as per your requirement .
Also you will find Select jquery Plugins section , where you will have to download the following plugins in order to make navbar work as intended :- Affix , Dropdowns,collapse

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old now but I found myself working through the same problems and want to provide a barebone example for anyone else who finds it. It is based on Bootstrap 3 though.

```
<nav class="navbar container" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_nav_container" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <!-- this are literally the "burger lines" and can be styled -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>      

    <!-- Note the ID here is the data-target of the button!! Critically important-->
    <div id="main_nav_container" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>your menu item here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```